# JSON Returning Null Crashes App

Tags: ios, json, null

I have some code that uses the Dribbble API to return a Shot, however, if any of the data in the JSON is Null, the App Crashes, I have tried to implement and catch that if it is null to move on, but that doesn't seem to work. Please can somebody advise?

Many Thanks

James

```
 self.JSONString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://api.dribbble.com/shots/1970521"];
NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:self.JSONString]];

__block NSDictionary *json;
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                                   queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                       completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {
                           if (data != nil) {
                               json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                                                      options:0
                                                                        error:nil];
                               NSLog(@"Async JSON: %@", json);
                           }
                           else {
                               return;
                           }
                       }];
```

Comment: Your app must be crashing after you process `json` which is `null`. The solution would be [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                                                      options:0
                                                                        error:nil]; can't parse your data, reason could be non-UTF data passed to it.

Comment: /questions/5716942/touchjson-dealing-with-nsnull

Comment: You should attach the XCode debugger to your application and post a crash backtrace, otherwise it's hard to help you. Is an exception thrown? What kind of a crash is it?

Comment: Note that `NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData` has an error parameter which is not used. NSLog `error` if is the result is nil.

Comment: Hi, Using the if (data !+ nil) stops my app from crashing now, but also stops any JSON being returned if i attempt to NSLog it after else { return; }

Comment: error says Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'data parameter is nil'

Comment: @JamesWalker The the issue is pretty clear, isn't it? You are passing `nil` as the data parameter to NSJSONSerialization, which is obviously an invalid operation. Therefore, your variable `data` is nil. I suppose the URL Connection was aborted, or a network issue happened. In your connection handler, gracefully handle the `connectionError` variable and only ever attempt to parse `data` if it is `!= null` and `connectionError == null`, meaning no connection error occurred. Otherwise, log the `connectionError` variable or provide an error dialog.

Comment: @Bensge Please could you provide a sample code? I have no idea how to do those checks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to handle connection errors appropriately.
Try something like this:

```
self.JSONString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://api.dribbble.com/shots/1970521"];
NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:self.JSONString]];

__block NSDictionary *json;
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
    queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
    completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError)
    {
        if (connectionError != nil || data == nil)
        {
            NSLog(@"Error loading dribble shot: %@",connectionError);
            //TODO: Show an alert to the user with UIAlertView?
        }
        else
        {
            NSError *jsonParsingError = nil;
            json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&jsonParsingError];
            if (jsonParsingError != nil || json == nil){
                NSLog(@"Error parsing JSON: %@",jsonParsingError);
                //TODO: User alert?
            }
            else
            {
                NSLog(@"Parsed JSON: %@",json);
                //Process parsed JSON, update UI, etc.
                //Keep in mind updates to the UI should be done in a main-thread call like this:
                dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^{
                    //Update UI here
                });
            }
        }
    }
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use 3rd-party Dribbble iOS SDK. It wraps all the Dribbble API, providing single-line api call methods, and also includes OAuth2 integrated flow and data models classes. Check out: https://github.com/agilie/dribbble-ios-sdk